# Multiplicative subgroups of $GL(V)$ which are almost additively closed

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-groups, finite-groups

## Edit:

According to comments  of  YCor and  Vincent, I revise the question.I  appreciate their  comments:

Let $G$ be a group.
We  say that $G$ is a *special group* if it is isomorphic to a subgroup $H$ of $GL(V)=\{T\in End(V)\mid \text{T is  invertible}\}$, where $V$ is a real or complex vector space and $H$ is almost closed under addition of $End(V)$; that is, $H+H \subseteq \mathbb{R}H$ or $H+H \subseteq \mathbb{C}H$.

Which finite groups are not special? Which Lie groups are not special?

Comment: Do you have a single example to motivate the question (beyond taking $G\subset\mathrm{GL}_1(\mathbb{K})$)?

Comment: Where do you use that $A$ is an algebra rather than 'just' a vector space?

Comment: @YCor  $S^1$ the rotation griup as a subgroup  of $GL(2,\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Vincent You are right. The vector space is sufficients. A special representation on a vector space.

Comment: @YCor  the situation which lead me to this question was the following: For every two independent vector $A,B$, the vector $ |A|B+|B|A$ is the  bisector direction. Then  i put $|A|=|B|=1$ this situation leads me to this post, indirectly.

Comment: @Ycor Ehm, doesn't $GL$ stand for general linear? I thought $GL(V)$ was defined as the set of all (hence general) linear transformations of some space $V$. E.g., $GL(3, \mathbb{R})$ and $GL(\mathbb{R}^3)$ being the same thing. You seem to use the notation differently. I guess in your definition $GL(A)$ is the set of invertible elements in $A$ such that 'my' $GL(V)$ would equal 'your' $GL(End(V))$?

Comment: @YCor  My apology for my delay. I had access to MO via my phone it was  difficult to communicate. I revise the  question.  I  should revise the  question since  my  question had a representation nature so it is  sufficient to assume that $A$ is  a  vector  space. I do not assume that the  representation is  finite dimensional.

Comment: Moreover I do not assume that the  difference $h-h'$ belongs $\mathbb{K}H$. But if we assume this  extra condition what can be said  about "Special groups"?As I  told already the indirect motivation for this question is the  concept of  bisector  of  two  vector $A,B$ wich is $|A|B+|B|A$. Now  if  $A,B \in O(n)$ then we leads to  $A+B$.  For example I was trying to give  a  contradictory result as follows: "SU(3) admit a [ social choice](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0723086904800161).

Comment: For  $A,B \in SU(3)$ we define the orthonormal part of the polar decomposition. this would gives a social  choice on SU3. On the  other hand it seems that it does not admit a social  choice.

Comment: @Vincent  Yes $GL(V)$ stands for linear  isomorphisms.